# how do I get a count for widgets in a wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I put multiple widgets (different widgets) in sidebar 1. how can I get a count of widgets in  sidebar1?

Comment: would you like to consider using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
echo count($widgets['sidebar1']);
```